# Review item notification staying after item is dealt with

Tags: bug

Over at codegolf.se I've noticed a minor, harmless annoyance: after reviewing the last item in my queue, the notification in the top-right doesn't disappear when I'm redirected to the "no reviews" page. It does, however, disappear if I then load another or refresh the same page.

The only place I have reviewing privileges is on codegolf.se, so I've only seen it there in case that matters.

Answer (score 4):

To explain what's going on, or clarify the issue for others:

This happens because each review is loaded onto the page via AJAX - the page itself never reloads, and the review count notification in the top right only updates to clear itself when a page is reloaded.

So when someone reaches the end of the review queue, the same old notification is still there, not having been updated, even if the user's emptied the review queue. It takes finally moving away from the page, or refreshing it, to update the count - or make it disappear, if the user's emptied the queue.

Comment: Ah, that totally makes sense. In that case, wouldn't that mean that it's not updating the count at all after each item is taken care of?

Comment: Correct - the top banner is never being reloaded, and the review count doesn't do any fancy independent updating like the inbox does. If it did update itself after each of your reviews, I suspect that on a site as active as P&CG, a lot of the time you'd see it climb down one or two items at a time whilst you're reviewing.